# XSLT text output escaping characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm processing an XML document and the output is text. The XML documents can have `<` which come in as `&lt;`
If I do nothing they come out as `<` in the text output. But I need them to stay as `&lt;`
I tried converting them to `&amp;lt;` but then it comes out as that.
I tried `disable-output-escaping`, but that only seem to work with xml output.
I guess the same applies for `&` and `>` if they turn up as `&amp;` and `&gt;`. But I have not run into that yet.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Johan

Comment: Please add samples of what you have input, your output and your expected output.

Comment: @Johan *"but that only seem to work with xml output"*. And what kind of output you actually need to use? Please post [MCVE] (simplified XML input, simplified XSLT, and the expected output)

Comment: Can you also say if you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you simply change the output method to "xml" (and omit the xml declaration)?

Comment: omit xml declaration was a super tip! I need to test it more. But it might solve another issue I have worked around in another way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: Please listen to Potane, har07 and Tim C to provide way more information in your question.

Second: This might help to narrow the problem down:

Putting the string out like `&amp;lt;` and having the output method set to text should be enough to get what you want.

However...

It could depend on the program you watch your output in if it converts it to an `<`.
Try Notepad/Notepad++ (or any other simple text editor) to view your code. A simple text editor shows the file as it is.

Answer (score -1):

Using an XSLT processor 1.0 or 2.0, the following xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&amp;lt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives `&lt;` as a result.

The problem may be your input data.

Hope it will help you.